# SqlMembershipProvider giving different results on dev machine and server(?)

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication

I'm trying to deploy an asp.net application.  I really suck at it.

Anyway, parts of it are protected using Forms Authentication using `SqlMembershipProvider`.  I've configured the membership provider to use a SQL server instance via Web.Config.

I can use the "ASP.NET Configuration" tool via Visual Studio to create new users.  That seems to work fine, and creates a new row in the database table for each user.

I can then log in to the protected areas using the newly created credentials.

That's all working nicely on the Visual Studio development debugging server.

The problem comes when I deploy it to the server.  After copying the entire directory tree (including Web.Config) for the project to the server and trying to log in, using *the exact same credentials,* it tells me "Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again."

How is this possible?

Ugh, I hate deployment.

### Update

I added the following code to the login page.  When I click on the page hosted from the server, the credentials can be used on the server to log in.

```
protected void CreateAdminButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.Security.Membership.DeleteUser("admin");
    System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser("admin", "asdfasdf", "admin@email.com");
}
```

The new admin record is visible in the same database.  The admin credentials *can not* be used to log in from the dev machine then.  This suggests some kind of keyed hash algorithm using different keys on server and dev box to me.

Comment: Did you upload the database as well? Or did you connect remotely to the server db when configuring accounts locally? Make sure that you have a database with users in it *on the server* as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use "/" for the application name parameter in your Membership provider, and define a custom Role provider as well. I just ran into this a few days ago.

You will now have to clean up the database manually, because you likely have 2 rows in the application table, and duplication in the user and role tables.

See http://cdonner.com/forms-authentication-custom-membership-provider-gotchas.htm.